# Do URL shorteners such as bit.ly affect SEO

Tags: seo, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO and URL Shortners](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22540/seo-and-url-shortners)

I am wanting to do tracking on links which I provide on my blog and was looking at something like bit.ly to do this, but I was wondering if this affects SEO due to all of my crosslinks going to the same domain.

Does anyone know if using url shortening linked content affects SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find this article interesting:
http://pingler.com/blog/url-shorteners-and-seo/

Looks like the jury is still out on this though. As a user of a website however, I do not trust shortened links (except on Twitter where they are common).

Comment: good point, I'm a bit wary of them as well. Perhaps i should just make it happen with some javascript or something.