# Do short URLs like goo.gl, bitly etc. affect your website ranking?

Tags: url, search-engines, ranking

I need to know whether using short URLs to back-link to pages affects your website ranking in the Google search results.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the URL shortener in question.    If implemented in an SEO friendly way, then using a URL shortener will not hurt your SEO efforts compared to direct linking.    For a URL shortener to be SEO friendly, it should:

- Use 301 permanent redirects not

  - 302 temporary redirects
  - framesets
  - meta refresh
- Allow crawlers to access it

  - Allow crawling with robots.txt
  - Don't include x-robots headers that limit crawling or indexing
  - Show the same redirect to users and search robots
- Be stable and robust -- consistent results with little downtime

Not all URL shorteners are SEO friendly.   You should check the above items for the one that you are using.